# Changing the UI and text display of lightning-input type="file"

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, slds, files, lightninginput

I want to change the UI of lightning-input type=" file". Current UI Look something like this:
[image]

But, I want the UI to be something like this:

[image]

Is it possible to change the styling and apply css or slds to get the desired UI in the lightning web component?

Comment: You can refer to the Lightning Design System guid https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/file-selector/#site-main-content

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change CSS of child components in LWC (in your case, lightning-input is the child), components can only manipulate the CSS of the component elements.
If you're using the component in a community, you can use the community general CSS to make the CSS changes that you want.